# how to press a enter button in cucumber & Ruby

Tags: ruby, cucumber

How can I press an Enter Button which comes from a message? My current ruby piece of code doesn't work properly. Any suggestions?

Cucumber:

```
Then I press the enter button
```

Ruby:

```
Then /^I press the enter button$/ do
  key_is_pressed("Enter")
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to send enter to a text field, you can use

```
find(".selector").set("something \n") # \n == return key
```

Or if you want [something more flexible](http://qastuffs.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-send-keystrokes-to-element-in.html):

```
class Capybara::Driver::Selenium < Capybara::Driver::Base
  class Capybara::Element < Capybara::Node
    def allowed_keys
      @allowed_keys ||= %q(option null cancel help backspace 
tab clear return enter shift left_shift control left_control
alt left_alt pause escape space page_up page_down end home
left arrow_left uparrow_up right arrow_rightdown arrow_down
insert delete semicolon equals numpad0 numpad1 numpad2 numpad3
numpad4 numpad5 numpad6 numpad7 numpad8 numpad9 multiplyadd
separator subtract decimal divide f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8
f9 f10 f11 f12)
    end

    def send(key)
      send_key = []

      if key.match(/\[.*\]/i)
        key.gsub!(/[\[\]]/,'')
        key = key.split(',')
      else
        key = [key]
      end

      key.each do |k|
        if k.match(/(\'|\")/i)
          send_key << k.gsub(/(\"|\')/, '')
        elsif allowed_keys.include?(k)
          send_key << k.to_sym
        else
          send_key << "#{k}"
        end
      end

      native.send_keys(send_key)
    end
  end
end
```

Also, you could check out [`send-keys`](https://github.com/markgandolfo/send-keys), a gem that (more or less) provides the functionality, albeit outdated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is harder than it should be.  Most recommendations are to have a hidden button i.e. off screen and 'press' it with capybara.  `send-keys` doesn't work across drivers with capybara because the `native.send_keys` is not consistent, and also not maintained (if I recall properly).  I think your best bet that I've found is to include the jquery simulate and inject an execute script with capybara in your step.

i.e.(?)

```
page.execute_script %Q{ $('.myfield').simulate( "keydown", { keyCode: $.ui.keyCode.ENTER } ) }
```

See https://github.com/jquery/jquery-simulate
and
https://github.com/j-ulrich/jquery-simulate-ext